# Splitting letters and numbers to figure out and assign value in table

Tags: python, split

I currently have some code in Python where I have entered the values from a table:

```
rules = {   "213" : ( 0.00019, 3.5, 0.00019, 3.5 ),
        "222" : ( 0.00019, 4.0, 0.00019, min( 4.0, 4.1E-8 * dm**3 - 4.1E-5 * dm**2 + 0.017 * dm + 1.35 ) ),
        "223" : ( 0.0003,  4.5, 0.0003,  4.5 ),
        "230" : ( 0.00017, 4.5, 0.00017, 3.3 ),
        "231" : ( 0.00027, 5.5, 0.00027, 5.1E-6 * dm**2 - 0.0057 * dm + 4.6 ),
        "232" : ( 0.00036, 6.0, 0.00036, 7.1E-6 * dm**2 - 0.007 * dm + 5.79 ),
        "239" : ( 0.00017, 4.5, 0.00017, 2.9 ),
        "240" : ( 0.00027, 6.5, 0.00027, 9.1E-6 * dm**2 - 0.01 * dm + 6.9 ),
        "241" : ( 0.00049, 7.0, 0.00049, 3.1E-5 * dm**2 - 0.032 * dm + 8.7 ) }
serialNumber = [ "name" ][ 0 : 3 ]
try:
    return rules[ serialNumber ]
```

The columns (readings from L-R in the brackets): F1ISO, F0ISO, F1COR, F0COR

What I would like to do, with an input 'name' (the name being a combination of numbers and letters and always in the form: 11111A for example, there can be two letters at the end).

I want to be able to split the 'name' into the letters and numbers but more importantly I am looking at the first 3 numbers and the letters. With these first three numbers I want to be able to read from the 'table' above but the values which are chosen also depend on the letter.

The main rules are:
 If the letter is equal to V then the 'ISO' values are taken.
 Any other combination takes the 'COR' values.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: is this a code speed contest ? what did you try ?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to assign the correct pairs of f0 and f1 depending on the name input.

Comment: I understand, what I meant to ask you was if you tried slicing your text entry, using if/else or similar things. Wanted to know where you got blocked in order to help you better.

Comment: I have tried various split functions but was getting confused on how to split up the numbers and the letters. I tried a gsub? I'm fairly new to all of this so I've been trying to find help on the internet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be helpful to understand how to get the two parts from your entry

```
>>> name =  "11111A"
>>> ser = name[:3]     # first 3 characters
>>> code = name[3:]    # rest of chars after the third
>>> ser
'111'
>>> code
'11A'
>>>
```

or maybe:

```
  >>> code = name[-1]     # last character
  >>> code
  'A'
```

then, in the same way:

```
>>> contents = rules[ser]
>>> if code == 'V':
...     print contents[:2]
... else:
...     print contents[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
name = "21311A"
serialNumber = name[:3]   # get first 3 numbers
rule = rules.get(serialNumber)   # get rule based on serialNumber
column = [3,1][name[5] == 'V']   # pick column based on last letter 
column -= int(name[4])           # shift column based on preceding digit

print rule[x]
```